# node, sails how to upload same file into two paths

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have created a function to upload image to a custom directory https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads .

code:

```
req.file('avatar').upload({
  dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images')
},function (err, uploadedFiles) {
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

  return res.json({
    message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!'
  });
});
```

how can I upload same file into 2 different paths.

the code I have tried:

```
   var imgPathArr;
   var dePathWeb = 'd:/images/web';
   var dePath = 'd:/images/mobile';

   imgPathArr.push(dePathWeb);
   imgPathArr.push(dePath);

req.file('file').upload({
            dirname: require('path').resolve(imgPathArr[0])
        },function (err, uploadedFiles) {
            if (err) return res.send(500, err);

            console.log("uploadedFiles web " + uploadedFiles[0].fd);

                       req.file('file').upload({
                            dirname: require('path').resolve(imgPathArr[1])
                        },function (err, files) {
                            if (err) return res.send(500, err);

                            console.log("files mobile " + files[0].fd);

                        });
                res.send("ok");
            });
       });
```

but each and every time the images are saved into a same path.

console:

```
uploadedFiles web c:\xampp\htdocs\meServer\images\secondNavi\000a073e-cd6c-4758-ab44-54d32ddfc20a.png
.
files mobile c:\xampp\htdocs\meServer\images\secondNavi\000a073e-cd6c-4758-ab44-54d32ddfc20a.png
```

why it always take the same path. the image is always only upload into the web directory. I'm defining the paths separately using array index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `fs`from node [DOCS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to copy this file.

Your code is really messy. Try to modulate that with a Controller + Service helper. Like `ImageController` dealing with `req` and `res` and `ImageService` to deal with everything else...

Comment: since this is an existing project i cant do any major changes... need to think  an alternative path for this with same implementation to upload into two different paths. :/

Comment: It is impossible without `fs` from core node. [Sails-skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) is not ready for that.

Comment: thank you, I was able to use fs.copyFile() after using req.file.upload(). after uploading the file I used fs.copyFile to copy that uploaded file into a different path.

Comment: I know, mask this question as answered!